# using the postgresql gem async

Tags: ruby, postgresql, asynchronous, eventmachine, goliath

I'm using [Goliath](http://postrank-labs.github.com/goliath/) (which is powered by eventmachine) and the postgres  gem `pg`, currently I'm using the pg gem in a blocking way: `conn.exec('SELECT * FROM products')` (for example) and I'm wondering whether there is a better way to connect to a postgres database?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `pg` library provides full support for PostgreSQL's asynchronous API. I've added [an example](https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/src/tip/sample/async_api.rb) of how to use it to the `samples/` directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'pg'

# This is a example of how to use the asynchronous API to query the
# server without blocking other threads. It's intentionally low-level;
# if you hooked up the PGconn#socket to some kind of reactor, you
# could make this much nicer.

TIMEOUT = 5.0 # seconds to wait for an async operation to complete
CONN_OPTS = {
    :host     => 'localhost',
    :dbname   => 'test',
    :user     => 'jrandom',
    :password => 'banks!stealUR$',
}

# Print 'x' continuously to demonstrate that other threads aren't
# blocked while waiting for the connection, for the query to be sent,
# for results, etc. You might want to sleep inside the loop or 
# comment this out entirely for cleaner output.
progress_thread = Thread.new { loop { print 'x' } }

# Output progress messages
def output_progress( msg )
    puts "\n>>> #{msg}\n"
end

# Start the connection
output_progress "Starting connection..."
conn = PGconn.connect_start( CONN_OPTS ) or 
    abort "Unable to create a new connection!"
abort "Connection failed: %s" % [ conn.error_message ] if
    conn.status == PGconn::CONNECTION_BAD

# Now grab a reference to the underlying socket so we know when the
# connection is established
socket = IO.for_fd( conn.socket )

# Track the progress of the connection, waiting for the socket to 
# become readable/writable before polling it
poll_status = PGconn::PGRES_POLLING_WRITING
until poll_status == PGconn::PGRES_POLLING_OK ||
      poll_status == PGconn::PGRES_POLLING_FAILED

    # If the socket needs to read, wait 'til it becomes readable to
    # poll again
    case poll_status
    when PGconn::PGRES_POLLING_READING
        output_progress "  waiting for socket to become readable"
        select( [socket], nil, nil, TIMEOUT ) or
            raise "Asynchronous connection timed out!"

    # ...and the same for when the socket needs to write
    when PGconn::PGRES_POLLING_WRITING
        output_progress "  waiting for socket to become writable"
        select( nil, [socket], nil, TIMEOUT ) or
            raise "Asynchronous connection timed out!"
    end

    # Output a status message about the progress
    case conn.status
    when PGconn::CONNECTION_STARTED
        output_progress "  waiting for connection to be made."
    when PGconn::CONNECTION_MADE
        output_progress "  connection OK; waiting to send."
    when PGconn::CONNECTION_AWAITING_RESPONSE
        output_progress "  waiting for a response from the server."
    when PGconn::CONNECTION_AUTH_OK
        output_progress "  received authentication; waiting for " +
                        "backend start-up to finish."
    when PGconn::CONNECTION_SSL_STARTUP
        output_progress "  negotiating SSL encryption."
    when PGconn::CONNECTION_SETENV
        output_progress "  negotiating environment-driven " +
                        "parameter settings."
    end

    # Check to see if it's finished or failed yet
    poll_status = conn.connect_poll
end

abort "Connect failed: %s" % [ conn.error_message ] unless 
    conn.status == PGconn::CONNECTION_OK

output_progress "Sending query"
conn.send_query( "SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity" )

# Fetch results until there aren't any more
loop do
    output_progress "  waiting for a response"

    # Buffer any incoming data on the socket until a full result 
    # is ready. 
    conn.consume_input
    while conn.is_busy
        select( [socket], nil, nil, TIMEOUT ) or
            raise "Timeout waiting for query response."
        conn.consume_input
    end

    # Fetch the next result. If there isn't one, the query is 
    # finished
    result = conn.get_result or break

    puts "\n\nQuery result:\n%p\n" % [ result.values ]
end

output_progress "Done."
conn.finish

if defined?( progress_thread )
    progress_thread.kill
    progress_thread.join
end
```

I'd recommend that you read the documentation on the [PQconnectStart](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PQCONNECTSTARTPARAMS) function and the [Asynchronous Command Processing](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/libpq-async.html) section of the PostgreSQL manual, and then compare that with the sample above.

I haven't used EventMachine before, but if it lets you register a socket and callbacks for when it becomes readable/writable, I'd think it'd be fairly easy to integrate database calls into it.

I've been meaning to use the ideas in [Ilya Grigorik's article on using Fibers to clean up evented code](http://www.igvita.com/2010/03/22/untangling-evented-code-with-ruby-fibers/) to make the async API easier to use, but that's a ways off. I do have [a ticket open](https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/issue/38/make-pgs-async-interface-play-nicely-with) to track it if you're interested/motivated to do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks Michael, this was very helpful. I found a gem that ties this to the EventMachine reactor in a relatively clean way here: https://github.com/jtoy/em-postgres

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can access postgres in a non-blocking fashion from goliath. I had the same need, and put together this proof of concept: https://github.com/levicook/goliath-postgres-spike

Answer (score 1):

I'm not (anymore) very familiar with Pg, but I haven't heard that any popular database could to async connections. So you still need to maintain a connection to the database for the duration of the query. Therefore you still need to block some where down the stack.

Depending on your application, you might already be doing it the best possible way.

But when you are dealing with some kind of polling app (where same client sends multitude of requests in short time) and it is more important to get the response out, even if it is empty, then you could write a ruby `Fiber` or flull blown thread or process that is long lived and proxies queries to the DB and caches the results.

For example: a request comes in from client A. Goliath app handles the query to the DB process with some unique ID and responds to the query with *'no data yet'*. The DB process finishes the query and saves results to a cache with the ID. When next request comes in from the same client, Goliath sees that it already has query results waiting, removes the results from the cache and responds to client. At the same time it schedules next query with the DB process so that it would be ready sooner. If the next request comes in before last one is finished, no new query is scheduled (not multiplying the queries).

This way your responses are fast and non-blocking, while still serving fresh data from DB ASAP. Of course they could be a bit out of sync with actual data, but again, depending on the application, this might not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to use an async adaptor to the database(Postgresql) in conjunction with an evented web server(Goliath) to gain performance. Mike Perham wrote a [PG activerecord adaptor](https://github.com/mperham/em_postgresql) for Rails 2.3 last year. Maybe you can use that.

As another example, Ilya Grigorik released [this demo](https://github.com/igrigorik/async-rails) of an async Rails stack. In this case the evented server is Thin, and the database is Mysql. Install the demo and try the benchmark with and without the EM aware driver. The difference is dramatic.

Comment: I'm trying to find a async adaptor to postgresql but I can't find any what will work on its on (without activerecord for example) and one that is being updated regularly

Comment: I'm afraid that you are too far ahead of the curve to count on anything like that at this point. Perham is good and he is responding to requests for help with getting it working in Rails 3. Here is a link to the postresql connection routine in the above mentioned adaptor just in case you missed it: https://github.com/mperham/em_postgresql/blob/master/lib/postgres_connection.rb